# Bootstrap Carousel with dynamic items does not slide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the stock bootstrap carousel:

```
<div id="main-navigation-carousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active" data-id="0">
      <ul>
        <li><a></a></li>
        ....
        <li><a></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By clicking on an anchor tag inside the carousel a new `.item` is injected to the `.carousel-inner`. After the `.item` is injected (which works fine) the carousel should slide to that `.item`. However, nothing happens.

```
<div id="main-navigation-carousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active" data-id="0">
      <ul>
        <li><a></a></li>
        ....
        <li><a></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-id="1">
      <ul>
        <li><a></a></li>
        ....
        <li><a></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-id="2">
      <ul>
        <li><a></a></li>
        ....
        <li><a></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Even if I use `$("#main-navigation-carousel").carousel(1);` in the browser console nothing happens. If I add items right in the code on the server everything works fine.

Comment: does your interval has a value? from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel: The amount of time to delay between automatically cycling an item. If false, carousel will not automatically cycle.

Comment: @BassJobsen naw. it should not cycle automatically. if I use `$("#main-navigation-carousel").carousel(1);` it should slide to the next item. But I think I figured it out now. If I enter `$("#main-navigation-carousel").carousel().data()` to console in the browser I can see that the carousel has just one item. which is wrong (`length: 1`). I think i need to refresh the items on the carousel. I just have to figure out how to do this.

Comment: also set your `carousel-indicators`, see: http://bootply.com/83370

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Removing the carousel data and then triggering it again does the job!

```
$("#main-navigation-carousel").carousel("pause").removeData();
$("#main-navigation-carousel").carousel(target_slide_index);
```

Since the carousel should not auto slide it is important to use `.carousel("pause").removeData()`.

Comment: this seems like a hack, is this the best way?

Comment: In what situation `.removeData();` make sense?

Comment: @BassJobsen If you do .carousel() on your element the carousel saves all items in it. On load I had just one item. If I add another one by clicking an anchor the carousel is not aware of that item. That's why I was not able to slide to it. Removing the data from the carousel and initializing it new by `.carousel(target_slide_index);` refreshes the items for the carousel. This makes it possible to slide to a newly added item.

Comment: @Stephan yeah, it's hacky but it's the only solution I'm aware of. If somebody has a better one I would be glad to hear it!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, anyone have a solution for Bootstrap 3?

Comment: @unclejam I've used Bootstrap 3!

Comment: @AndreZimpel I'm getting an error that 'target_slide_index' is not defined.

Comment: @unclejam yea, `target_slide_index` is one of my own variables. You could also do `$("#main-navigation-carousel").carousel(2);`

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```html
<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" id="car_id"></ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" id="car_inner"></div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

```js
//json data result = [{"id_img": 17,"img_filename": "ca0d8455-2702-4560-a444847429e36670.jpg"},{"id_img": 18,"img_filename": "eb0c6c77-fbd7-4f2c-bf22-10c874eefbf6.jpeg"},{"id_img": 19,"img_filename": "e7568c87-babb-4049-aed6-27b97866a817.png"}]
    var x = $.getJSON('../Json/GetImage', function (data) {
      $("#myCarousel").carousel("pause").removeData();
      var content_indi = "";
      var content_inner = "";
      $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
        content_indi += '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' + i + '"></li>';
        content_inner += '<div class="item" style="background:url(&#39/images/' + obj.img_filename + '&#39) no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"></div>';
      });
      $('#car_id').html(content_indi);
      $('#car_inner').html(content_inner);
      $('#car_inner .item').first().addClass('active');
      $('#car_indi > li').first().addClass('active');
      $('#myCarousel').carousel();
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Robert : on the first page load, when Bootstrap find ".carousel()" it renders the carousel object. So, the "slide" event is bound on the carousel. This solution is to "stop" the "slide event" first, then remove all object within carousel container using ($("#myCarousel").carousel("pause").removeData()), fill the carousel element then finally tell Bootstrap to render carousel object again using .carousel(); Btw .carousel(target_slide_index) is not necessary, in fact I got an error while using it.  I'm using Bootstrap 3 and .. sorry for my English.

Comment: Note that `car_id` should be replaced with `car_indi`

Answer (score 1):

as in http://bootply.com/83370 with your carousel having class `.carousel`

```
$('.carousel').carousel({interval:false});
$('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="item"><img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#555:#5555" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="900x500"><div class="carousel-caption"><h3>Third slide label</h3><p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p></div></div>');
$('.carousel-indicators li').removeClass('active');
$('.carousel-indicators').append('<li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>');
$('.carousel').carousel('next');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
//json data result = [{"id_img": 17,"img_filename": "ca0d8455-2702-4560-a444847429e36670.jpg"},{"id_img": 18,"img_filename": "eb0c6c77-fbd7-4f2c-bf22-10c874eefbf6.jpeg"},{"id_img": 19,"img_filename": "e7568c87-babb-4049-aed6-27b97866a817.png"}]
    var x = $.getJSON('../Json/GetImage', function (data) {
      $("#myCarousel").carousel("pause").removeData();
      var content_indi = "";
      var content_inner = "";
      $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
        content_indi += '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' + i + '"></li>';
        content_inner += '<div class="item" style="background:url(&#39/images/' + obj.img_filename + '&#39) no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"></div>';
      });
      $('#car_id').html(content_indi);
      $('#car_inner').html(content_inner);
      $('#car_inner .item').first().addClass('active');
      $('#car_indi > li').first().addClass('active');
      $('#myCarousel').carousel();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .active class from all the items:

```
$('.item').removeClass('active');
```

And then move the active class to the item that you just created with the anchor. E.g.:

```
$('.carousel-inner').append(`<div class="item active">...</div>`);
```

This works at least for Bootstrap 4:
https://jsfiddle.net/gal007/kt3jLopz/20/