# jQuery .on() to create content carousel dynamically from list

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a simple ajax call to get certain information from a sharepoint list and create a carousel from it.

I think I need to use .promise() or .on() in order to load this after the for loop has gone through the list so I add an object to the carousel, but am lost in how make this happen.

Here is what my loop looks like. It does get all the data correctly.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                    response = '<article class="item"><img src="' + data.d.results[i].Image_x0020_URL + '"><div class="carousel-caption"><h3>' + data.d.results[i].Title + '</h3><p>' + data.d.results[i].Content + '</p><p><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Read More</a></p></div></article>';
                    indicator = '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="'+i+'" class="active"></li>';
                }
```

After the for loop, I append my info to my carousel:

```
$('#homepageItems').append(res);
$('#indicators').append(ind);
```

My carousel code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner" id="homepageItems">
      <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" id="indicators">
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-controls"> <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"> <span class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></span> </a> <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"> <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span> </a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have added the for loop into a varible:

```
var loop = function(){forloop in here}
```

and then added

```
$.when(loop()).done()....
```

This does loop through all the results and shows me that when fires via alert("finished"); i put inside the when, but the carousel is not rendering.

How do I load the object to the carousel after the for loop has completed?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `.on` to create the carousel.

See the answer to this question:  [Bootstrap Carousel with dynamic items does not slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029224/bootstrap-carousel-with-dynamic-items-does-not-slide)

So after your for loop, you would just do this:

```
$.ajax( {
   url: '/carousel',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
      var response = '',
          indicator = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
          response += '<div class="item"><img src="' + data.d.results[i].Image_x0020_URL + '"><div class="carousel-caption"><h3>' + data.d.results[i].Title + '</h3><p>' + data.d.results[i].Content + '</p><p><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Read More</a></p></div></div>';
          indicator += '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="'+i+'"></li>';
      }
      $('#homepageItems').append(response);
      $('#indicators').append(indicator);

      // set up the first slide as "active"
      $('.item').first().addClass('active');
      $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
      $("#myCarousel").carousel();
     }
});
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XPpaPAW156qMpnMje7Hp?p=preview).

Comment: Don't I need to have append happen in the for loop?

Comment: As soon as this slides from slide 1 to 2 the slides disappear?

Comment: Why are you using the `article` tag instead of `div` - not sure what impact that will have on the carousel? If you inspect the carousel when it stops sliding using the developer tools/Firebug, are all the dynamically added elements there?

Comment: the carousel shows with article or div either way when i manually fill it. Dynamically, I see all of the items in dev tools and it moves fwd through the slides automatically, but when i click an indicator they disappear and the prev/next buttons dont show either. Getting there :)

Comment: Got this working in a plunker. In the `for` loop you need to use `+=` as an operator, and set the "first" slides as above. See the plunker as an example.