# Knockout data-bound bootstrap carousel issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having difficulties updating/rerendering a bootstrap carousel control data bound to a Knockout observable array (self.Notes). I have greatly simplified the provided code because it was too much other wise.

Everything renders fine on page load, but when self.RemoveNoteFromReviewSetup is called and the array is modified, the carousel completely disappears. When I inspect the dom all the markup is there and the markup reflects the changes knockout should make to the dom. However, and this is the strange part, when only the first (index 0) element of self.Notes is updated the carousel renders again based on the updated array self.Notes. When any subsequent item in the array is changed the carousel disappears.

I have left out a lot of code so if you need to see anything else, please let me know.

This is driving me crazy and I am considering just firing a page reload command so everything renders from the start. However, this undermines the entire Knockout approach of course.

Any pointer is greatly appreciated.

Html:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Reviews -->
<div class="flashcards-controls">
<button id="btnSlideRight" class="btn btn-custom pull-right flatleft flatright" data-bind="click: NextNote"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></button><button id="btnSlideLeft" class="flatleft flatright btn btn-custom pull-left" data-bind="click: PrevNote"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></button>
<div class="container text-center">
    <span class="badge badge-notecounter"><span data-bind="html: NoteCounter"></span> / <span data-bind="html: Notes().length"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container flashcards" id="flashcards-container">

<!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
<div id="fashcardsCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-wrap="false" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    @*    <ol class="carousel-indicators" data-bind="visible: Notes().length > 1, foreach: Notes">
            <li data-target="#fashcardsCarousel" data-bind="attr: { 'data-slide-to': $index }, css: { 'active': $index() == $parent.CurrentNoteIndex() }, click: $parent.NextNote"></li>
        </ol>*@
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" data-bind="foreach: { data: Notes, afterRender: $parent.postCarouselRenderEvent }">
        <div class="item" data-bind="css: { 'active': $index() == $parent.CurrentNoteIndex() }">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                <button data-bind="click: ToggleTagEditor, attr: { id: 'btnTagEditor' + GlobalClientId() }" class="btn btn-sm btn-custom">
                                    <i class="fa fa-tags fa-fw"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-custom">
                                    <i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button data-bind="click: ShowInfo, attr: { id: 'btnInfo' + GlobalClientId() }" class="btn btn-sm btn-custom">
                                    <i class="fa fa-info fa-fw"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <h5><strong data-bind="    text: Title"></strong></h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" data-bind="html: Content, visible: Content">
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" data-bind="style: { display: IsLoading() == false ? 'none' : '' }">
                            <div class="text-center text-muted">
                                <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i><br />
                                Loading note content
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <!-- ko if: Notes().length > 1 -->
    @*<a class="left carousel-control"We added support for all common image types. In other words, pictures will now show up when you review your @evernote notes :-) href="#fashcardsCarousel" data-slide="prev" data-bind="click: PrevNote"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#fashcardsCarousel" data-slide="next" data-bind="click: NextNote"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>*@
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- /.carousel -->

</div>
<div id="popoverStagingArea" data-bind="foreach: { data: Notes, afterRender: $parent.postTagPopoversRenderEvent }" style="display: none;">
<div data-bind="attr: { id: 'tagEditor' + GlobalClientId() }">
    <select multiple></select>
    <p class="text-muted text-center" data-bind="visible: TagsUpdating" style="margin: 0;"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></p>
    <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'tagRemovalConfirmation' + GlobalClientId() }" style="display: none">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-custom btn-block" data-bind="click: RemoveTagPendingRemoval">Only remove tag from note</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-custom-warning btn-block" data-bind="click: RemoveTagAndDeleteNoteFromReviewSetup">Also remove note from filter</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-block" data-bind="click: CancelTagRemoval">Cancel</button>
        <p class="text-center" style="margin-top: 3px;">(<a data-bind="click: TagRemovalExplainer().slideDown('fast')" href="#">what is this?</a>)</p>
        <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'tagRemovalExplainer' + GlobalClientId() }" style="display: none;">
            <p>
                When you setup filter <strong data-bind="text: $parent.SetupName"></strong> you selected tag <span class="label label-success" data-bind="text: TagPendingRemoval().Name"></span> as part of the search criteria. We thought you might want to have the option to either just remove the tag from the note and save it to Evernote, or also delete this note from any subsequent reviews that are part of <strong data-bind="text: $parent.SetupName"></strong>.
            </p>
            <p class="text-center">
                (<a data-bind="click: TagRemovalExplainer().slideUp('fast')" href="#">hide</a>)
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

JS:

```
        function Review(reviewItem) {
        //code removed//
            self.RemoveNoteFromReviewSetup = function (note) {                   
                var apiRemoveNoteString = "/api/review/" + self.Guid + "/note/" + note.Guid;
                $.ajaxq("notes", {
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: apiRemoveNoteString,
                    headers: { "Authorization": "Token " + $.cookie("rat") },
                    success: function (replacementNote) {
                        var originalNoteIdx = self.Notes.indexOf(note);
                        self.Notes.replace(self.Notes()[originalNoteIdx], new Note(replacementNote, self));
                        self.Notes()[originalNoteIdx].GetContent();
                        console.log(self.Notes()[originalNoteIdx]);
                        self.Notes()[originalNoteIdx].InitTagEditor();
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("We could not remove a note for you at this time. Please try again later.");
                    },
                    complete: function () {

                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a simple jsfiddle demonstrating the issue

Comment: I sympathize, but I'm afraid you have both still too much code, as well as too little code in your question for us to (conveniently) help you. It's too much, as there's many things in there that are surely *unrelated* to the problem. It's too little, as it's not enough to *reproduce* the issue (try to make a Stack Snippet, with the editor toolbar, to [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your issue).

Comment: Maybe this post will be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029224/bootstrap-carousel-with-dynamic-items-does-not-slide

Comment: Thanks you all for you interest and mental support. I fixed the problem. Please view my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. It had nothing to do with Knockout. After taking another good look at the rerendered carousel markup, I noticed that no one slide had the class "active", which Bootstrap uses to determine the current slide. After adding this class manually/programmatically like so:

```
var slide = $("#yourselector")[slideIndex];
$(slide).addClass("active");
```

the entire carousel became visible again with all behaviors intact :-).

Here's another 1.5 days of my life I am not going to get back but I will console myself by telling myself that I have gained valuable knowledge into the intra library workings of Knockout and Bootstrap...